# Merge request [vfp] and [visual-foxpro]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[vfp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vfp) is an abbreviated form of the [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) tag (both referring to `Visual Foxpro`).

I would suggest to merge into [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) as it is the "standard" way of tagging.  For example, we already have a [foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxpro) tag.

Can we merge [vfp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vfp) and [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro)?

Comment: What about `foxpro` ?

Comment: I haven't worked with Foxpro but imagine that there is a distinction (based on the fact Foxpro was from the MSDOS-era).  Microsoft have a knowledge base article highlighting differences.

Comment: Sadly - I do remember the dos foxpro days :) However, the tag wiki for it (and tagged posts) could do with a review - it seems to be geared towards vfp as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[vfp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vfp) -> [visual-foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) merged and syn'd.